# Can libsvm return predict results as signed distances?

Tags: opencv, svm, libsvm

Based on the documentation of libsvm, prediction results are either predicted class labels or probability estimates of classes. I want to get prediction results as signed distances to the margin.

Which is implemented in OpenCV, documentation is as follows:

> **C++**: float CvSVM::**predict**(const Mat& sample, bool **returnDFVal**=false )
>
> const **returnDFVal** – Specifies a type of the return value. If true
>   and the problem is 2-class classification then the method ***returns the
>   decision function value that is signed distance to the margin***, else
>   the function returns a class label (classification) or estimated
>   function value (regression).

Full documentation can be found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html#cvsvm-predict).

How can I use svm-predict.exe with this functionality, or can I use it?

Answer (score 0):

Fine, for those who just don't know what is *SVM*, I copied the function you may need to check out here:  https://gist.github.com/blackball/0350fbe8d6783cbf41ee

Begins at line 27, the array *prob_estimates* is what you need. Write another predict function that output *prob_estimates* should be very simple.